# Drupal: accordion inside node

Tags: php, jquery, drupal, user-interface

I see there are several nice Accordion (UI) modules, but none seems to be able to display accordion for subsections of a single node/article.
E.g. article on my site has sections "Start", "Middle", "End" and I'd like to be able to see these sections wrapped each under other on a single node page.
Like
/node/x

- Start (text available upon clicking)
- Middle
- End

Have I missed some good module for this?
Or should I write sunch a functionality from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you should change `node.tpl.php` to manually break node into sections.

Answer (score 4):

Originally from www.chrisherberte.com/blog/drupal-7-and-jquery-ui-accordion:

> Now that jQuery UI is included in D7 core, we'll see a lot more
>   application style functions using the UI library. Here's a quick
>   example for adding an accordion to node content (enable and select PHP
>   filter) demonstrating how easy it is to add jQuery UI effects and
>   widgets in Drupal 7.
>
> ```
> <?php
> drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.accordion');
> drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function() {jQuery("#accordion").accordion();});','inline');
> ?>
> <div id="accordion">
> <h3><a href="#">Section 1</a></h3>
> <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
>
> <h3><a href="#">Section 2</a></h3>
> <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
>
> <h3><a href="#">Section 3</a></h3>
> <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
> </div>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I inserted accordion markup inside specific node to get it working, e.g. :

```
node text here
<div id="accordion">
<h2>section name</h2>
<div> section body</div>
.....
</div>
node end text here
```

Of course, JQuery accordion was also included into page.tpl.php